# Disable Export Options in ReportViewer Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have this ReportViewer issue, I am trying to remove the Export to PDF option on the ReportViewer toolbar, I am using this code which I found while googling:

```
protected void rvMainViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string exportOption = "PDF";
    RenderingExtension extension = rvMainViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(exportOption, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (extension != null)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(extension, false);
    }
}
```

The code is executing without errors, but, the PDF still appears as an option, although the code is very common on the internet and I did not see anyone complaining about it.

I still have the option to export to PDF on the ReportViewer control.

The code is simple and there is nothing related to the viewer to show in this post.

**UPDATE:**
I also tried placing the code in the ReportViewer PreRender event with no luck.

Can anybody point out where the issue might be?

Comment: Have you tried ReportViewer1.HasExportOption = false?

Comment: No, I need the export options, I only want to remove the PDF option from the drop down list.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working" ? I previously used something similar and it should hide the PDF option on the export dropdown.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu The code is actually executing but I still get the option PDF.

Comment: I've just check the code exactly as you posted it and it works as expected, PDF is no longer visible. Check that you're not reinitializing the viewer or overwriting this in any way after the code is executed.

Comment: There's no code that is relevant to the report viewer.

Comment: Which version of report viewer control are you using ? Also you can consider just "hiding" it via css.

Comment: Also in worst case you can always put your own export buttons above or below the report viewer control, hide the export options & hook the buttons to perform export without any reflection magic.